# What is the decoding error percentage of (7,4) Hamming code?

Tags: coding-theory

The decoding error occurs where there are more than 1 bits that are flipped. Hence, if the probability that a bit is flip is $10\%$, then shouldn't the decoding error percentage be $1-0.1\cdot0.9^6\cdot7-0.9^7 = 0.149$? Why my textbook (by MacKay) claims that it is $7\%$?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, an $(m,n)$ Hamming code means $m$ bits total of which $n$ are data (the others being used for error correction).  Do you mean a $(7,4)$ Hamming code?

Comment: What you have calculated is the _word_ error rate: $14.9\%$ of the time, the decoder output will be the wrong codeword. But what is of interest is the _bit_ error rate of the decoded data bits. Even when the output of the decoder is the wrong codeword, _some_ of 4 data bits might still be correct.

Comment: @DilipSarwate how is the bit error rate 7% then? i can't get it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $E$ denote the event that the output of the decoder is a codeword that
is not the same as the transmitted codeword, and let $E_i$ denote the event
that the $i$-th *data* bit in the output codeword differs from the $i$-th data bit of the transmitted codeword. Clearly we have that
$$E = E_1 \cup E_2 \cup \cdots \cup E_k.\tag{1}$$ since if *none* of the $E_i$
occur, then the data bits in the output codeword are all correct and so
the output codeword must be the same as the transmitted codeword.

Now, in general, the events $E_i$ are *neither independent events nor equiprobable events.*  The *Bit Error Rate* (BER) for the decoded data bits, denoted by $P_b$ here, is defined as the arithmetic average of the $k$ $P(E_i)$ values. It is generally quite time-consuming to determine the values of the $P(E_i)$ or their average $P_b$ except for codes of very short blocklengths, whereas $P(E)$, the probability that the decoder output is not the same as the transmitted codeword, is easier to determine (or overbound for bounded-distance decoders that are prone to
decoder failure). It is straightforward to show that
$$\frac 1k P(E) \leq P_b \leq P(E)\tag{2}$$
which in the instance that is puzzling the OP tells us that the BER 
must be between $3.725\%$ and $14.9\%$.  More can be said in this
particular case, however, the codewords of a $[7,4]$ Hamming code
are very closely related to what is called a *biorthogonal signal set*
in the communications literature (the codewords of the
$[8,4]$ extended Hamming code are *exactly* a biorthogonal signal set).
For a biorthogonal signal set, the BER is very nearly $\frac 12P(E)$, and so the $7\%$ BER claimed in the Mackay text can be explained 
as being consistent with this result, with some differences because the $[7,4]$ Hamming code is not quite a biorthogonal signal set, and because $P_b$
is *not exactly* $\frac 12 P(E)$ for a biorthogonal signal set.

Masochists who really want to delve into the details can find information
about orthogonal and biorthogonal  signal sets and their relationship to first-order Reed-Muller codes (of which class the $[8,4]$ extended Hamming code is an example) can find some basic information on pp. 161-180 of [this ancient Lecture Note of mine](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece461/spring98/book1/Signal_Space.pdf).

Comment: i don't quite get the first inequality above. Do you mind explaining more? Shouldn't the probability of error of each bit be the same such that you don't need to take average?

Comment: also why is k = 4 and not 7

Comment: $k=4$ because there are 4 data bits. The decoder output is always a valid _codeword_. This codeword _cannot_ match the transmitted codeword in the 4 data bits and differ from the transmitted codeword only in the parity bits. _Think_ a little bit about why this must be so before demanding an explanation and read the last part of the first paragraph to see how $(1)$ follows from all this. Now, $$P(E) \leq \sum_{I=1}^k P(E_i)$$ (again, think a bit about how this follows from $(1)$) and dividing both sides by $k$ gives the first inequality in $(2)$. ....  (continued)

Comment: .. (continuation)... It doesn't matter in the least whether the $P(E_i)$ are all the same (they aren't in general) or different, If the $P(E_i)$ are all the same, then $P_b$ also has the same value and the stated bounds on $P_b$ apply to each $P(E_i)$ also. If the $P(E_i)$ are different, then the bounds on $P_b$ don't necessarily hold for all the $P(E_i)$.